# Python For Loops has a colon between two numbers

Tags: python, for-loop

What exactly does a for loop with a colon instead of a comma do? I have a list and a for loop printing all of the items in the list.  Sorry if this is really simple but I have attempted finding an answer online and I am somewhat new to Python.

```
import requests from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://talksport.com/football/572055/") soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

clubs = soup.findAll("h3")

for club in clubs[17:-2]:
   # do something
```

Comment: Please show us some code and what you've tried so far

Comment: Please give [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example])

Comment: You mean the `clubs[17:-2]`? This is nothing directly related to loops, but a way to only select certain parts of the sequence `clubs`. This is called *slicing*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: I think you should check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon has nothing to with the for loop, it's just slicing a list. I will give you an example.

Let's say you have a list like this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

When you slice the list, you get only the part of the list you ask for, for example:

```
my_list[0] # This is the first element of the list
my_list[-1] # This is the last element of the list
```

You can combine these with a colon like this:

```
my_list[2:5] # The elements between index 2 and 5
```

In this case, that would be

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

In your specific case,

```
clubs[17:-2] # The elements between index 17 and the second to last index.
```

Since I don't know what is in your list I will give a similar example with my list:

```
my_list[4:-2]
```

Which returns

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: And just to make sure I answer what you ask, slicing the list in the loop just changes which elements go into your for loop.